# FFMPEG Precise Overlay

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-editing

Lets get straight to the point, I'm having a problem with ffmpeg's overlay feature. I have two videos. One is 2865 frames, the second is 2865 frames. Both are at 30000/1001 fps. I've checked both of their timestamps before overlaying and logged it to a file which I would overlay to my post as an image had I the reputation, so for now you'll just have to trust that I'm telling the truth when I say their timestamps are exactly the same.

Now despite the video framerates matching, the result of this command:

```
"ffmpeg", "-i", fmt.Sprintf("%s%s", CCME.PathsToUse[0], CCME.UnderlayVideo),
                   "-i", fmt.Sprintf("%s%s", CCME.PathsToUse[1], CCME.VideoName), 
                   "-filter_complex", "overlay=0:0", "-vsync", "0", "-crf", "18", "-y", "-shortest", "-strict", "-2",
                   fmt.Sprintf("%s%s.%s", CCME.PathsToUse[2], CCME.FinalVideoName, CCME.VidFormat
```

Results in two extra frames being added to the end of the video, which would be fine as I can exclude or remove additional frames added to the end. However when run through analysis, the following warnings pop up:

```
Frame 770: Repeated

Frame 1500: Repeated

Frame 2276: Repeated

Missing Or Mangled Frame(s) After Frame 2591

QR DATA: 2593

3 frames repeated and or added.
```

It seems that despite the exact framerate, frame number, and timestamps being used, ffmpeg has a hard time overlaying the video in such a way as to align each frame to its respective frame for the other video. For the purpose of this project I need absolute accuracy in how these frames are aligned and am not getting this. I've been banging my head against the wall for two weeks now and haven't come up with an answer as to why this is happening or what further options I can use to prevent the frame duplications, drops, and added frames to the end of the video.

Does anyone have any idea as to why this would be happening and what is missing in the command above or what can be added to get these videos to line up and or prevent repeats and dropping of frames? As far as I know, this shouldn't be happening but it seems everything I've done so far has failed to fix it.

Comment: Run your command with -report added and share the report.

Comment: Good to see you again, Gyan. Do you need the entire log? It's quite long. Or is their a specific portion I can extract and share?

Comment: Full log, please. Host it elsewhere if needed.

Comment: Alright, posted it to drive. Here's the link: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1YU1sqKidpT_Lfi04b-oCxhTmhL3Gal25

Comment: Framerates and durations aren't identical. Run `ffmpeg -i file -an -f mkvtimestamp_v2 filepts.txt` for both files and compare.

Comment: Gyan, it looks like ffprobe isn't returning an accurate result for the framerate or timestamp. I may end up parsing the shell output of ffmpeg -i file in order to get the exact framerate, which in the case of the two videos was 29.99 vs 29.97. I think that your ffmpeg -i file -f mkvtimestamp_v2 quickly helped me identify the problem and deduce what was going wrong. If you want to put that as your answer I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two files don't have identical framerates or duration. But if you're sure the main video is meant to be constant framerate, you can generate new smooth timestamps for both video streams and then perform the overlay.

```
ffmpeg -i main.mp4 -i overlay -filter_complex
    "[0]setpts=1001*N/30000/TB[m];
     [1]setpts=1001*N/30000/TB[o];
     [m][o]overlay=shortest=1"
 -crf 18 out.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

While Gyan was given the answer I'm going to go over how I got this to work.

Because the chances of myself being able to match the exact duration and framerate of a movie and thus get a perfect overlay of two videos is improbable at best, impossible at worst, I decided to take an alternate approach.

Frame perfect overlay can be done by deconstructing the target video to its individual frames:

```
exec.Command("ffmpeg", "-i", fmt.Sprintf("%s%s", CCME.PathsToUse[0], CCME.UnderlayVideo),
                             "-start_number", "0", "-qscale:v", "2", fmt.Sprintf("%s%s%%d.jpg", TempDirPath[0], VideoName))
```

Overlaying the frames individually:

```
for x:=0; x<len(files)-2; x++ {
    overlayFile := exec.Command("ffmpeg", "-i", fmt.Sprintf("%s%s%d.jpg", TempDirPath[0], VideoName, x),
                                "-i", fmt.Sprintf("%s%s%d.png", CCME.PathsToUse[1], CCME.VideoName, x),
                                "-filter_complex", "overlay", "-y", fmt.Sprintf("%s%s%d.jpg", TempDirPath[1], VideoName, x))
```

(Note: -2 wouldn't need to be there in most cases. The TempDir this is done in contains a subdirectory and audio file that needed to be accounted for.)

Then Reconstructing the video based off of the framerate and videotype, grabbed by parsing the output of ffmpeg -i file:

```
cmdConstruct := exec.Command("ffmpeg", "-framerate", AudioFS[1], "-i", fmt.Sprintf("%s%s%%d.jpg", TempDirPath[1], VideoName),
                            "-c:v", "libx264", "-crf", "18", "-pix_fmt", "yuv420p", "-y",
                            "-vsync", "0", "-strict", "-2", fmt.Sprintf("%s%s.%s", CCME.PathsToUse[2], CCME.FinalVideoName, VideoFormat))
```

Using this method the audio also needed to be re-added. In my case simply ripping the audio from the main file and muxing it over the new video worked for me.